# Capturing An Error Code From SQLite With Python

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

In a Tkinter GUI based script, I am updating, deleting and inserting using an SQLite3 database. Everything works correctly until I enter a record ID that does not exist in the database. It usually happens accidentally but could happen if I am trying to delete a record id that is not in the table.

For example, here is some code:

```
def delete_coin():
    cursorObj.execute("DELETE FROM coin WHERE id=?", (portid_delete.get(),))
    con.commit()
    messagebox.showinfo('Portfolio Notification', 'Coin Deleted From Portfolio!')
    reset()
```

This function is executed from a button. If the id exists, the record is deleted and the screen reflects this. However, if the record doesn't exist, everything appears normal but the last row of the screen shrinks. This only happens if a record id that does not exist is entered from UPDATE or DELETE.

I am trying to figure out how I can detect an error for this condition and eliminate the execution of messagebox and reset in the script, just send a message that the id (or whatever field) was not found.

How can I capture that errorcode?

Comment: Have you considered doing a query in the id before doing the delete, and then having conditional logic based on what the query returned?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an "error" per se, it simply didn't find any rows to delete.

Likely the [`rowcount`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) attribute would help.